# not able to insert the value received from getextra

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

I am retrieving the value from previous activity using getextra and putextra 
But at the time of insertion in database the variable is loosing the value saved in it or becomes null.
I am not able to understand what might be the issue.
please go trough my code.
insertion is done on last click of radio button

```
package com.tmm.android.chuck;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.tmm.android.chuck.db.DBAdapter;
import com.tmm.android.chuck.quiz.GamePlay;
import com.tmm.android.chuck.quiz.Question;
import com.tmm.android.chuck.util.Utility;

/**
 * @author Sanket Naik
 * 
 */
public class QuestionActivity extends Activity implements
        OnCheckedChangeListener {

    private Question currentQ;
    final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
    private GamePlay currentGame;
    Calendar C = Calendar.getInstance();
    String text, topic1;
    String mon = C.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1 + "";
    static int a = 0;
    ArrayList<String> getselect = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.question);

        // Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (a < 1) {

            topic1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("itemname");

            Log.i("sanket", topic1);
        }
        /**
         * Configure current game and get question
         */
        currentGame = ((ChuckApplication) getApplication()).getCurrentGame();
        currentQ = currentGame.getNextQuestion();

        RadioGroup rdgb = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.group1);
        rdgb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        /**
         * Update the question and answer options..
         */
        setQuestions();

    }

    private void setQuestions() {
        // set the question text from current question
        String question = Utility.capitalise(currentQ.getQuestion()) + "?";
        TextView qText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        qText.setText(question);

        // set the available options
        List<String> answers = currentQ.getQuestionOptions();
        TextView option1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        option1.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(0)));

        TextView option2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        option2.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(1)));

        TextView option3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        option3.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(2)));

        TextView option4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
        option4.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(3)));
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (a > 0) {
            switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

    }

    private boolean checkAnswer() {
        String answer = getSelectedAnswer();
        if (answer == null) {

            return false;
        } else {

            if (currentQ.getAnswer().equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {

                currentGame.incrementRightAnswers();
            } else {

                currentGame.incrementWrongAnswers();
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    public String getSelectedAnswer() {
        RadioButton c1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        RadioButton c2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        RadioButton c3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        RadioButton c4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
        if (c1.isChecked()) {
            return c1.getText().toString();

        }
        if (c2.isChecked()) {
            return c2.getText().toString();
        }
        if (c3.isChecked()) {
            return c3.getText().toString();
        }
        if (c4.isChecked()) {
            return c4.getText().toString();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

        a++;

        if (!checkAnswer())
            return;

        /**
         * check if end of game
         */
        if (currentGame.isGameOver()) {

            try {
                db.open();
                String total = currentGame.getRight() + "";
                db.insertOptions(topic1, total, mon);
                db.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Intent i = new Intent(this, EndgameActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            a = 0;
            finish();
        } else {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }

}
```

Insertion is taking place but the value of topic1 is not being inserted, value of mon,total is being inserted.Just the first column of table is blank
but at same time in OnCreate() when I am printing the value of topic1 it is being displayed

Comment: Please show the code of db.insertOptions() and database create table statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alway use putExtra to send value to another activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, EndgameActivity.class);
i.putExtra("itemname", Value) // Value can be almost of any type
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Check this:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: U did not got me
I am receiving the value here on this page which I want to insert it into database

Comment: Okay sorry, my bad! Please provide the code from the method db.insertOptions(topic1, total, mon); so i cant see if that good in there because from what i can understand in the code above, everything should be working correctly